# Can't find the /etc/tor/torrc file on Alpine Linux

Tags: configuration

I'd like to extend the Docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/rdsubhas/tor-privoxy-alpine/~/dockerfile/ to include exposing the Tor control port at 9051. This would involve, after installing `tor` on the container, to make some modifications to `/etc/tor/torrc`.

However, I'm not able to find this file after installing Tor on Alpine Linux. First I run Alpine Linux in a container using the command

```
docker run -it --rm alpine:latest /bin/ash
```

Then I run the command

```
apk --update add tor
```

which results in an `OK` confirmation. But if I thereafter try

```
cat /etc/tor/torrc
```

I get

> cat: can't open '/etc/tor/torrc': No such file or directory

Why doesn't `apk --update add tor` produce an `/etc/tor/torrc` configuration file?

Comment: You don't want to be doing work to a docker container after you've built it to fix the config, you want to edit the Dockerfile to make the changes to the final build. There is no torrc file, it operates on defaults adding your own as as simple as adding a new `COPY` line to the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd really have to ask the people behind Alpine why they decided to pack it that way. If you need a torrc copy the template from `etc/tor/torrc.sample`. In many cases the defaults, which are used if `torrc` doesn't exist, are already enough.